How to revoke all invitelink of Channle/Group telegram api
I  created invite link with request admin approval.
await botApi.CreateChatInviteLink(-100123654, memberLimit: 1, createsJoinRequest: true);

I want to revoke all invite like that created manually in Channel/Group.
can i revoke it with telegram bot api???
